# converting percentage values into numbers in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am getting hold of data from google sheet(consisting of 26 columns) into a python dataframe. 4 columns A,B,C,D have data in the form of % values(eg 15.6%) and also contain some rows with N/A values. I am trying to convert these columns into numbers so that I can use them for other calculations, but am having problems doing so. The output for all the rows is 1.0000 using my code, but I want it to be 0.156(from 15.6%)
This is the code I am using

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df = df.replace(r'%', '', regex=True)
cols = ['A','B','C','D']
df[cols] = df[cols].str.astype('float').div(100)
```

I have been trying to find a solution for the past 3 hrs, but nothing seems to work:/
I feel the main problem here could be the presence of N/A values which can't be transformed using the astype()
Sample dataset:
[image]

Solution: Thanks to @PraysonW.Daniel

```
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce").div(100)
```

Comment: "_but am having problems doing so_" what is your problem? You forget to mention them! Please try to [edit] your question and add them.

Comment: My problem is that the code does not work

Comment: Can you share dummy data including one with possible `NaN`?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel sure, I'll attach it with the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: if you walk through your code step-by-step, do you get what you expect on earlier steps? that is, do your replace steps work but the converting to float fails? or do the replaces fail?

Comment: Hi @scotscotmcc, the replaces work, it's only the conversion step that does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the steps I took

```py
import pandas as pd

…

dataf.loc[:, ["A","B"]] = (dataf
 .loc[:, ["A","B"]]
 .replace(r"%","", regex=True)
 .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
 .div(100)
)
```

First I selected the columns we are interested in, then replace `%` with `` , force values to numeric and last divided by 100

### Data and Results

```py
# generate data
dataf = pd.DataFrame({"id":["lgloo",]*3,"A":["75%", "10%",""], "B":["20%","0", "0"]})

…
dataf

    id       A      B
0   lgloo    0.75   0.2
1   lgloo    0.1    0
2   lgloo    NaN    0
```

Comment: this solution worked perfectly well and gave the output that I wanted. Thanks thousands for your solution and for the explanation. I'll probably look further into your solution and try to understand how each function works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.strip('%')` on each column.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip('%').astype('float').div(100)
```

Comment: I tried this already, and it did not work